# Dependency injection results with unnecessary implementation

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I am creating an *Animal* class which implements *IAnimal* interface. Then, both *Cats* and *Dogs* classes implement *IAnimal* interface. Currently I keep only 3 simple methods inside *IAnimal* for short demonstration. The main class *Animals* is constructed by using Dependency Injection (DI).

When *IAnimal* has more methods, for example: *Cats* class only implements *SomethingOnlyCatsDo* method, *Dogs* class implements *SomethingOnlyDogsDo* method, then there will be more unnecessary implementations inside each of those classes (like *Cats().CatchDisk()* or *Dogs().CatchMouse()* in current example).

My question is, is there any way which can help me keep using DI but avoid this growing of unnecessary implementations?

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    void Sound();
    void CatchMouse();
    void CatchDisk();

    // What if there are more methods here
    //string GetOwnerName();
    //void SomethingOnlyCatsDo();
    //void SomethingOnlyDogsDo();
}

public class Cats : IAnimal
{
    public void Sound()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Meow meow");
    }

    public void CatchMouse()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Catching mouse");
    }

    public void CatchDisk()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Dogs : IAnimal
{
    public void Sound()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Woof woof");
    }

    public void CatchDisk()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Catching disk");
    }

    public void CatchMouse()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

// Main class
public class Animals
{
    private readonly IAnimal _animal;

    public Animals(IAnimal animal)
    {
        _animal = animal;
    }

    public void Sound()
    {
        _animal.Sound();
    }

    public void CatchADisk()
    {
        _animal.CatchDisk();
    }

    public void CatchAMouse()
    {
        _animal.CatchMouse();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are correct that you would have a large mess and are doing it badly.
You probably need ICat and IDog interfaces which carry the appropriate method signatures for Cats or Dogs as well as the IAnimal interface.

Comment: I tried to create ICat and IDog but then Animals class constructor will require two dependencies of ICat and IDog also. In this case, I am trying to simplify it to use only one dependency (as IAnimal). Or did I get it wrong with the assumption of two dependencies?

Comment: You are breaking "Interface Segregation Principle" by throwing exception in `CatchMouse`. Read about SOLID principles.

Comment: For things that implement IAnimal, they must be actions that are common to all animals.

Comment: What does your question have to do with Dependancy Injection?

Comment: @buffjape in client code I would use:
var animal = new Animals(new Cats()) or new Animals(new Dogs())
animal.Sound()
That is how I understand Dependency Injection is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).

> The interface-segregation principle (ISP) states that no client should be forced to depend on methods it does not use.

Your `IAnimal` interface will only have `Sound()`, then you make a new interface called `ICat` that inherits from `IAnimal` and this interface will have `CatchMouse()`. Your class `Cats` will inherit from `ICat`.

[Here's](https://www.oodesign.com/interface-segregation-principle.html) a practical example.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. I still have another question regarding the same implementation logic above. Assuming I made a method in Animals class named: CatchSomething, then I have to check type of _animal (passed in constructor) whether it is a type of Dog or Cat to invoke corresponding CatchDisc or CatchMouse. Is there any other way to for CatchSomething() method to know which method in Dog or Cat to call without checking _animal type?

Comment: To achieve this, your constructor type must be `IAnimal` and this interface must have a `Catch()` method. Your classes that inherit from `IAnimal` must implement this method, cats can still catch mouses and dogs can still catch disks. If you have an animal that doesn't implement `Catch()` then you're breaking the ISP (Interface Segregation Principle) again, to fix it you must make two new interfaces like `ICanCatchAnimal` and `ICantCatchAnimal` (not exactly these names but you get it!!) and they inherit from `IAnimal`, this is *segregation*

Answer (score 3):

If following SOLID principles, and especially the I (Interface Segregation, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle), `IAnimal` should not have  `CatchDisk` or  `CatchMouse` methods. Instead you should have  `IAnimal` with the  `Sound()` method, and separate interfaces  `ICatchesMouse` and  `ICatchesDisk`. This way no  `Animal` has to implement unnecessary methods.